# When can I get specific blueprints?

Tags: rogue-legacy

From [the wiki](http://rogue-legacy.wikia.com/wiki/The_Blacksmith):

> On your first playthrough of the game, you will find blueprints up to the Sky equipment (unless the player opens a Golden chest in the secret room activated by Calypso's Compass, which can give higher-level equipment), but the best equipment can only be found in the Dungeon or by defeating mini-bosses. In NG+, after beating the final boss for the first time, all of the equipment save the dark equipment becomes available; you will mostly find the new equipment in chests, but will rarely find blueprints for older equipment instead, especially once you have found all the new equipment.
>
> The blueprints for the Dark equipment can be found after defeating the final boss in NG+ by fighting mini-bosses such as Botis, Barbatos & Amon, Stolas & Focalor, and Sallos. They can also be found in NG+ using Calypso's Compass.

I'm on my first playthrough, I already defeated the four bosses but didn't touch the final boss yet because I didn't have all pieces of Sky equipment yet, and since I'd like to get the all equipment achievement I was worried that - as per the wikia - advancing to the second playthrough would prevent me from doing that.

However, even before I completed the Sky equipment, I started getting Retribution equipment from The Land of Darkness! Even more, now I got a piece of Imperial equipment from a regular chest in The Land of Darkness! I'm confused because this is contrary to what is said by the wikia.

When can I safely defeat the final boss and advance to the second playthrough without being worried that this will prevent me from getting some lower level pieces of equipment?

Comment: This doesn't answer your Q (I don't know the answer) but when I played, I didn't find the sets aquired all in a row.  So just because you get different pieces, doesn't mean you won't get the older stuff as far as I know.  You just have to be persistant.

Comment: Doesn't that wikia quote say that when you advance to NG+, all equipment (except dark) gets unlocked automatically?

Comment: @MartinEnder Perhaps. My understanding was that once I advance to NG+, I can FIND all equipment except dark. Because otherwise, the rest of the sentence "*you will mostly find the new equipment in chests, but will rarely find blueprints for older equipment instead, especially once you have found all the new equipment*"  wouldn't make much sense, would it?

Answer (score 1):

Having all pieces of Retribution set but one, all previous sets completed and even quite a few pieces from later sets, I defeated final boss and advanced to NG+.

Once there, I started getting worried: I already got almost whole Slayer set, but still couldn't find the last piece of Retribution set.

But now I finally got the last piece of Retribution set from Botis in Maya.

My guess is, the quote from Wikia is outright wrong.